# Is $\prod \limits_{i = 1}^{n} [0,1] \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ homeomorphic to the closed unit ball?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Is $\prod \limits_{i = 1}^{n} [0,1] \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ homeomorphic to $\bar B(\theta , 1)$ , the closed ball centered at origin with radius $1$?

Can someone please give some reference links to study elementary techniques to deal with homeomorphism and to show two given spaces homeomorphic ?

Comment: The only way of proving that two given spaces are homeomorphic in general is to construct a map and show that it is a homeomorphism. Some times it's easy, some times it's tricky.

Comment: Does the ball also live in $R^n$?

Comment: You havn't given details in which space the ball belongs to?

Comment: Although I am unable, at this moment, to construct an explicit formula for a homeomorphism, it seems that they should be homeomorphic. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, imagine a unit square $\left[0,1\right]^2$ inscribed in the unit disk. First, consider that the square is rigid while the disk is freely malleable, and then push the disk along its boundary down to the square's boundary. This seems, to me, to be a continuous deformation. Similarly, if you consider that disk is rigid, you can pull out the sides of the square until they meet the boundary of the disk. Maybe this will help you find such a map.

Answer (score 3):

First translate and scale the cube so that it is centered at the origin with side length 2. This map is a homeomorphism.

Now consider the following map from this new cube $C$, to the unit closed ball $B$.

$$ f \colon C \to B $$
$$ f(x) = \frac{|x|}{d_x}x $$

where $d_x$ is defined to be the distance between the origin and the point where the line segment from the origin through $x$ intersects $C$. This map is continuous with continuous inverse and so is a homeomorphism.

Hence as the composition of two homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism we have your desired result.

Comment: There is probably still things to check. For instance, continuity is clear everywhere but at zero, where you have to use that $d_x$ is bounded.

Comment: Yes agreed, I wasn't sure what level of detail to go for. I didn't want to obscure the intuition. Edit: although continuity is clear at 0, you mean to say that $d_x$ is non-zero everywhere.

Comment: This proof can be extended (but it's more details to check) to show that every closed and bounded convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that has non-empty interior is homeomorphic to the unit ball in that space. The idea is the same: from an interior point, extend rays emanating from that point, all of which lie inside the convex body, up to some unique boundary point. Then map all these segments to the corresponding one in the unit ball wrt $0$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : Could you please give the exposition of the convex set case , as a separate answer . Or should I open a new question asking this ?